# React Bootstrap hide/show eye icon

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I have password field like this. I want to put an eye icon at the end of the password field to show/hide password.

```
  <Form.Control
                    size="lg"
                    type="password"
                    placeholder="Password"
                    style={loginStyle.regualrText}
                    className="mt-3"
                    onChange={e => {
                        const val = e.target.value;
                        setLoginData(prevState => {
                            return { ...prevState, password: val }
                        });
                    }}
                />
```

I couldn't find this in React bootstrap. In the following way, the problem can be solved by adding a button to the end.

```
      <InputGroup className='mt-3'>
                    <FormControl
                        id={'Password'}
                        size="lg"
                        type={passwordState.type}
                        placeholder="Password"
                        style={loginStyle.regualrText}
                        className="pass-wrapper"
                        onChange={e => {
                            const val = e.target.value;
                            setLoginData(setState => {
                                return {...setState, password: val}
                            });
                        }}
                    />
                    <InputGroup.Append>
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-danger" type="button"
                                onClick={() => setPasswordState(setState => {
                                    return {
                                        ...setState,
                                        type: 'password' ? 'text' : 'password',
                                        name: 'Show' ? 'Hide' : 'Show'
                                    }
                                })}>{passwordState.name}
                        </button>
                    </InputGroup.Append>
                </InputGroup>
```

**Is there any way I can fix it by adding an eye icon?**

Comment: You can use react-icons: https://react-icons.github.io/react-icons/

Search for 'eye' and you get a few eye icons that might fit your ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add InputGroup.Text under InputGroup.Append

```
<InputGroup.Append>
    <InputGroup.Text>
        <i onClick={clickHandler} class={showPass ? 'fas fa-eye-slash' : 'fas fa-eye'}></i>
    </InputGroup.Text>
</InputGroup.Append>
```

You have to add cdn link of font-awesome in head block of html.

Answer (score 0):

Hide/show eye icon for the password in javascript & reactjs

```
   function click() {
        // toggle the type attribute
        const togglePassword = document.querySelector("#togglePassword");
        const passwordV = document.querySelector("#password_field");
             const type = passwordV.getAttribute("type") === "password" ? "text" : "password";
        togglePassword.className === 'fa fa-eye viewpass mr-4 text-muted' ? document.getElementById("togglePassword").className = 'fa fa-eye-slash viewpass mr-4 text-muted' : document.getElementById("togglePassword").className = 'fa fa-eye viewpass mr-4 text-muted';
        passwordV.setAttribute("type", type);

    }

<input type="password" id="password_field"/>

<span className="fa fa-eye viewpass mr-4 text-muted" onClick={click} id="togglePassword"></span>
```

In add CSS

```
.viewpass{
  float: right;
  margin-left: -25px;
  margin-top: -26px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: large;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this [example](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/docs/forms/input-group/#example) on the react-bootstrap page:

```
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import InputGroup from "react-bootstrap/InputGroup";
import { Eye, EyeSlashFill } from "react-bootstrap-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faEye, faEyeSlash } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

function BasicExample() {
  const [showPass, setShowPass] = useState(false);
  const clickHandler = () => {
    setShowPass((prev) => !prev);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <InputGroup className="mb-3">
        <InputGroup.Text id="password-input">
          <Key />
        </InputGroup.Text>
        <Form.Control
          type="password"
          name="password"
          placeholder="Password"
          aria-label="password"
          aria-describedby="password-input"
          required
        />
        <InputGroup.Text onClick={clickHandler}>
          {/* You can use both. I ran into some width issues with FontAwesome but they can be fixed by playing around */}
          {/* <FontAwesomeIcon icon={showPass ? faEyeSlash : faEye} /> */}
          {showPass ? <EyeSlashFill /> : <Eye />}
        </InputGroup.Text>
      </InputGroup>
    </>
  );
}

export default BasicExample;
```

This is the result:

[image]